# Start Activity on DeviceAdminDisable Request

Tags: android, android-activity, device-admin

I am trying to start new Activity on onDisableRequested of DeviceAdminReceiver in Android 4.1.2 But It takes much time to start new Activity and my app is no more DeviceAdmin I am Using following Code .I want that my Activity will start first than "onDisableRequested" msg

```
   public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(context,InformationActivity.class);
        LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    return "onDisableRequested";
}
```

Comment: Have you got any solution of it? I am stuck with same prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching I got this Answer
It is not possible in Android 4.1.2

Comment: they may possibly doing something else but not Starting Activity in onDisableRequested